# Codeigniter can only display default controller

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter 3.1.8. It works fine on my localhost. However, when I push it to FTP server, I can only access the the default controller page. When I tried to access other view that has other controller, it gives me error '404 Not Found'

config :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://*****.net/my_project/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['encryption_key'] = 'xRUqKhsoZ5qV6y3kqARFJFdPqJvp7X2z';
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

route :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

I have tried several .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /materials-library/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
      ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# Set the rewritebase to your CI installation folder
RewriteBase /sandbox/ci/


# Send everything to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can i send runnable ci structure ??? i think problem is in your structure..

Comment: I don't think so. Because I try it with CodeIgniter template, by creating one other simple controller and  view. It still have the sampe problem.

Comment: put this .htaccess file into your system folder as bellow

<IfModule authz_core_module>
 Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
 Deny from all
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working for me. Make sure The file must be called ‘Yourcontroller.php’, with a capital ‘Y’.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure you have loaded uri library (application/config/autoload.php)

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
```

Check out controller naming convention here:https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html. Hope this will help you.

Greeting!

Comment: I've tried it, still not working. Thanks for your advice by the way.

Answer (score 0):

> it's normal problem and For fixed it you have to define .htaccess file in you folder. as bellow
>   both file in your folder.
>   put this file in your main folder and assign name Of .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

> put this file in your application folder and assign name Of .htaccess

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
  Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
  Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Comment: $config['encryption_key'] = ' ';

Comment: remove encpt key value

Comment: plz try now it's woking or not ??

Comment: No, it is still not working. Still gives the same error 404 not found

Comment: check yor main folder , system folder and controller .htaccess file is present or not ???

Comment: I have .htaccess file in my system folder and application folder, but not in controller. Do we need .htaccess in controller folder?

Comment: Yes, I have .htaccess on my main folder. I have put th .htaccess file inside controller folder as well. Still not working.

Comment: So i have tried to use the template file with welcome_message controller. I create another controller for  another view and put a link on the welcome view to access the second view. No model used. I've placed .htaccess file inside folders as you advice. It still can display the default controller page. Please help.

Comment: send me your mail id i send you runasble ci structure

Comment: my mail, purbabernando88@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
1) first controller name and class name first character capital letter
   example :: CapturistaCtrl
2) go to config changes ::
   -> $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; remove index.php
   -> $config['uri_protocol']   = 'REQUEST_URI'; remove (REQUEST_URI)
3) .htaccess
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
   </IfModule>

set .htaccess file 

List item
```

Comment: I've done it, but still not working. It can only display the default controller page